# Imagick not converting large .tif files

Tags: php, imagick

I am using Imagick to convert large .tif images into jpeg. For some reason when .tif files are bigger than 4GB the function that uses Imagick does not work. When files are less than 4GB, there is no problem with it. It does not show any messages, it just keeps running for ever. I have waited days and it never finishes.

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23

```
<?php
// Function used to create Thumbnail
function CreateThumbnail($sourcePath, $destPath, $fileExtension)
{
    $maxCoreNum = 4; // set maximum number of cores
    
    if (strtoupper($fileExtension) == "TIF" || strtoupper($fileExtension) == "TIFF") {
        $tempPath = str_replace("thumb.jpg", "temp.tif", $destPath);

        $command = 'gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED" -ot Byte -scale "' . $sourcePath . '" "' . $tempPath . '"  2>&1';

        exec($command, $output);

        $image = new Imagick($tempPath);

        $image->setImageColorspace(255);
        $image->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $image->setCompressionQuality(60);
        $image->setResourceLimit(4, $maxCoreNum); //Set maximum number of cores to use with ImageMagick
        $image->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
        $image->setImageAlphaChannel(11); // Use this instead.
        $image = $image->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN); // Use this instead.

        $image->setImageFormat('jpeg');

        $image->resizeImage(300, 0, Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
        $image->writeImage($destPath);

        $command = 'rm "' . $tempPath . '"';
        exec($command);


    } elseif (strtoupper($fileExtension) == "GIF" || strtoupper($fileExtension) == "JPG" || strtoupper($fileExtension) == "JPEG" || strtoupper($fileExtension) == "PNG") {
        $image = new Imagick($sourcePath);

        $image->setCompressionQuality(60);
        $image->setResourceLimit(4, $maxCoreNum); //Set maximum number of cores to use with ImageMagick

        $image->setImageFormat('jpeg');

        $image->resizeImage(300, 0, Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
        $image->writeImage($destPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: How much smaller is 'smaller'? Have you seen what happens with a 3GB or 2GB file? 4GB is a _humongous_ size for an image. How long have you waited for it to complete? Do you get the same result if you run this from the command line?

Comment: @RoAchterberg by smaller I mean files < 4GB. I have waited for days to complete and it never finishes. I have not try to run it from the command line.

Comment: So you're saying a file with a size of 3.9GB _did_ complete? Sounds like you need to do some more careful testing. Try incrementally upping the size in 0.5GB increments and see where it chokes.

Comment: Just on a side note, exactly what is this an image of? Do you really need it to be that big? If you're looking for resolution, perhaps look for a vector based format?

Comment: They are images of crop fields. They can have a size up to 25GB of size.

Comment: 25GB?! Holy moly!

Comment: is your server a linux server or a windows server ??

Comment: It is a linux server running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Also, I don't see you doing any error checking on any of the ImageMagick calls. You should probably add some debugging checks.

Comment: Check your resource limits and edit your policy.xml file for image width. If this is a shared server from some hosting company, then they may have restrictions and they would have to make edit to the policy.xml file. `convert -list resource` will tell you your limitations. Also be sure you have a current libtiff installed that has BigTIFF compatibilities.

Comment: @fmw42 I have libtiff5 (4.1.0+git191117-2build1) that supports BigTIFF files.
I have also change the configuration on the policy.xml file depending on the limitations. I am waiting for it to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you asked about imagick and this might not be useful, but I help maintain [php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips), an image processing library designed for very large images. It should have no problems with your huge TIFFs. For example:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

// fast thumbnail generator
$image = Vips\Image::thumbnail($argv[1], 128);
$image->writeToFile($argv[2]);
```

Will make a 128x128 thumbnail of an image. I can run it on a huge TIFF like this:

```
$ vipsheader ~/pics/x.tif
/home/john/pics/x.tif: 108199x81503 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, tiffload
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e 3./try1.php ~/pics/x.tiff y.jpg
164840:579.02
```

So on this modest laptop it thumbnailed a 108,000 x 82,000 pixel TIFF in about 10 minutes and needed a peak of 160MB of RAM. That image is tiled and JPEG-compressed, you'll obviously see different performance with other TIFF types.

There's a chapter in the docs about the thumbnail operation and how to get the best from it.

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html

The php-vips API docs are here:

https://libvips.github.io/php-vips/docs/classes/Jcupitt-Vips-Image.html

Comment: The actual command that I am using to do so is ```vipsthumbnail file.tif -o "file.jpg[background=255 255 255]" --size=300``` This will create a 300x300 jpg picture with a white background.

Comment: Ah OK. You should just be able to use `vipsthumbnail file.tif -o file.jpg[background=255] --size=300` if you like, it's slightly simpler.